# How can i test website activated in App_Offline

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm adding App_Offline.htm file to root directory. i don't know how to test my web.

How do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't test the application when you have the `App_Offline.htm` file in your root directory because it's purpose is to take down your application on the server.

Comment: I want System Maintance message still shows users. web test only show me

Comment: Do you want to show message to user that maintenance is going on, while you want to test the application side by side?

Comment: Can I ask why it will take much time ?

Comment: I'm upgraded IIS6 to IIS7. But my web don't work on IIS7. I'm finding problem. In this time use App_Offline.

Comment: I think app_offline maybe have configuration like **customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"**

Comment: Normally, there are two hosting environment will be used, one is QA and other one is production, once we test all what we have done and its tested it in QA, then that same will be moved to production environment. Otherwise suffer it if you have only deployment environment.